# Cheersing vs cheering

Tags: is-it-a-word, neologisms, verbing

I have come across the word "cheersing", with an "s", as opposed to what I believe to be the correct form: **cheering**.

I think it comes from a misguided verbification of the exclamation "cheers!", as in the plural of the noun "cheer".

However since there is already a corresponding verb, "to cheer", I don't see why anyone would need to force a plural noun into a progressive verbal form like "cheersing".

Besides, it's impossible to conjugate and hilarious to even try:
I cheers
you cheers
he **cheerses**
we cheers
you cheers
they cheers

Please tell me that cheersing is only a made up word.

Comment: "_I have come across the word 'cheersing', with an 's'..."_ ~ It's much easier to answer questions like this when you specify **where** you've come across the word. The question might be handled differently depending on where you saw it.  Facebook?  It  might be a typo.  Urban Dictionary?  Maybe it's slang.  The New York Times editorial page?  Maybe it's a coined word by a creative writer.  A scientific journal?  Maybe it has some narrow use in a highly technical field.  During a presidential debate?  Maybe it's a play on words, or maybe it's a slip of the tongue.  Provide context, please.

Comment: "I think it comes from a misguided verbification of the exclamation "cheers!", as in the plural of the noun "cheer"." - why 'misguided'?

Comment: @J.R.: good point. It appears in technical document about a job I am working on. In the document it refers to the "act of raising a glass".

Comment: This strikes me as griping disguised as a question.

Comment: @MetaEd You are likely right, but does that make the question any less interesting or valid?

Comment: @tmslnz Actually, yes it does. From the posting guidelines: “avoid asking subjective questions where … it is a rant disguised as a question: ——— sucks, am I right?” Thank you for asking.

Comment: @MetaEd I disagree. Three very constructive answers, lots of comments and all effectively *answering* my question. Yet according to your critique, they all answered a non-question.

Comment: @tmslnz: Three answers and lots of comments may all answer your question, but that doesn't necessarily mean your question is a good fit for this forum.  MetaEd never said this was a non-question, or not an interesting question; he merely wondered aloud if it was appropriate for EL&U, according to pre-established and published guidelines. I wouldn't call that a 'critique,' but I would call that a fair question.

Comment: I certainly found this question interesting. It _does_ have an urbandictionary definition. It also returns 47,000 hits on Google as opposed to the slightly saner version—_cheers-ing_—only returning 33,000. In many ways, it's similar to the misspelling of lying as _lieing_, which returns a whopping 2.1 **million** hits. Perhaps, it could have been worded better or reworked with a different approach.

Comment: This is the way a word is born.
This is the way a word is born.
This is the way a word is born.
Not with a pang but a lot of whining.  (apologies to T.S. Eliot)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's certainly not a word that I have come across, and I believe that it is not a real word.

That said, I have *once* heard someone say "we were cheers'ing all night in celebration".

That is, the pseudo-word "cheersing" describes the act of saying "Cheers!".

In addition, it's use is not prevalent in literature according to [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cheersing,%20cheering&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Comment: I think it could only have a very specific use, say at a formal dinner with a succession of toasts. "We gave the Loyal Toast and drank the health of twenty others. We were cheersing all night!"

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I concur, entirely.

Comment: My son used to use this word when he was 5 or 6. All little kids become fascinating with toasting at some point.

Answer (score 6):

Looking in [Google books](https://www.google.com/search?q=cheersing&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22cheersing%22&oq=%22cheersing%22&gs_l=serp.3...15392.17973.0.18793.2.2.0.0.0.0.322.430.0j1j0j1.2.0...0.0...1c.kQYFP2HFtzk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=793d93ed3f02aeae&biw=1958&bih=854), "cheersing" does not mean the same as "cheering". It's the act of raising a glass (or clinking a glass with somebody else) and saying "cheers".

In at least two of the roughly ten books you can see it in, someone uses it and somebody else says that it's not a real word. I would agree.

It also seems to be found in the past tense—["cheersed"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cheersed%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)—but not in the present.

Comment: Yes, I was just posting something similar.

Comment: Note the Danish equivalent of "cheersing", the verb [skåle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sk%C3%A5le), is indeed a real word.

Comment: In that context, it would be obvious as to what the word means.  So, I agree - it's not a real word but you can get away with it in that context.

Answer (score 3):

The usual word in English for "[cheersing](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cheersing)" is "toasting". Instead of, "we cheersed him", one would normally say "we toasted him".

The usage is uncommon and appears to be a slang neologism or perhaps [a nonce coinage by those unfamiliar with the word "toasting"](http://www.styleforum.net/t/242033/etiquette-for-cheers-ing) in this sense.

Comment: In my vocabulary, it doesn't mean quite the same thing as "toasting". "Toasting" is the act of raising a glass and saying "here's to John". [American Heritage Dictionary](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/toast_2) agrees: *The act of raising a glass and drinking in honor of or to the health of a person or thing.*

Comment: @PeterShor That's a very subtle distinction indeed, if there is one at all, and *perhaps* why the neologism arose. In my own experience   that action would be called "toasting" whether one said "Here's to John", "Cheers", or "Cin cin".

Comment: that is indeed a subtle distinction, but I suspect it's the reason the not-yet-a-word "cheersing" was coined.

Comment: Let me rephrase the distinction. I think that if you lift a glass in honor of something or somebody, you're "toasting", whether you say "here's to John" or "cheers". But if you clink glasses without it specifically being in honor of somebody or something, that's "cheersing". Of course, since I don't use the word "cheersing", I might be wrong. But I wouldn't use "toasting" for that action, either.